# Run Jar in Console

Tags: java

I am writing a java applicaiton that outputs strings via System.out and I just want to know how to run this application outside my IDE. I have an executable jar. What does one do to see this output in a console?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Basically: `java -jar app.jar`

[Sun's site](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) has more info

Comment: What about a deployment solution that just requires end users to double click on the file? Batch file?

Comment: Note that this solution requires that you set the main class entry point: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: I get a `Headless exception` if I run that in pure console. Is there a way to do this without an `X` server?

Answer (score 11):

As others have suggested:

```
java -jar JarFIle.jar
```

Note this requires you to set the main class [entry point](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

If you don't/can't set Main-Class then you would do:

```
java -cp JarFile.jar package.Classname
```

Additionally if you associate jar file types with your JRE then double click should work too.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood what you want,
`java -jar JarFile.jar`
should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I would like to help future people

You can also make another file next to it and just double click on it example:

Windows: anynameyoulike.bat

Linux: anynameyoulike.sh(Not sure this works but it should)

and in that file add

`java -jar JarName.jar`

Answer (score 0):

```
jar -tf JarName.jar
```

It will give list files in jar

```
Drive://Jarlocation> java -jar jarName.jar
```

it will execute your jar from console

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you must run it from `cmd.exe` to see the console, if you're using Windows. (Maybe `Terminal.exe` of Linux does the same) You cannot just double-click the `jar`, even if you enable Console in <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> - <kbd>Java</kbd> - <kbd>Advanced</kbd>.

Now, to run it, use `cd` to enter the folder where you put the jar, and:

```
java -jar name_of_your_jar.jar
```

You can see it all now.

To output the text, right-click on the top-left icon of the `cmd` window, and <kbd>Edit</kbd> - <kbd>Mark</kbd>, drag to select text, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy it.