# Could not find Main class while running Storm Topology

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am using `storm jar` class to submit Topology to `nimbus'. It works fine locally but on remote cluster it says it could not load main class. Below is the error

```
stderr: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/storm-0.9.0.1/lib/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/storm-starter.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Error: Could not find or load main class ExclamationTopology
```

I am running following command on CLI:

```
usr/local/storm/bin/storm jar /tmp/storm-starter.jar ExclamationTopology
```

Answer (score 5):

For me it was a classpath Issue. Once I traversed to the directory where the jar was present, and ran the command everything was working fine.

Running from storm home folder

```
./bin/storm jar examples/storm-starter/storm-starter-topologies-0.9.3.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology TOne

Failed with error: Error: Could not find or load main class storm.starter.WordCountTopology

Running from directory examples/storm-starter

/root/storm/apache-storm-0.10.0/bin/storm jar storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology TOne
```

Worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

There has probably been an issue with the packaging of storm-starter.jar: this jar should not contain the sl4j implementation. In order to package the storm-starter example (https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter), run the following command from the root folder (where the m2-pom.xml is present):

```
mvn -f m2-pom.xml package
```

This should produce this file in the target/ folder:

```
storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Then, in order to deploy it to the cluster (indeed, through Nimbus), you need to tell to the `storm jar` command the fully qualified name of the class that contains the `main()` that provides the topology definition, like this (make sure you use the one with "-with-dependencies"):

```
usr/local/storm/bin/storm jar storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

Comment: True. I made on within IntelliJ-IDE which added extra libs.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error for storm, & it got fixed by adding provided in pom.xml. When u add provided, maven doesn't bundle those libs into the jar.

Answer (score -5):

try running like this :

```
java -jar /tmp/storm-starter.jar ExclamationTopology
```

got the answer here: [Run Jar in Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619196/run-jar-in-console)

Comment: Wrong wrong wrong! You answer has nothing to do with Storm

Comment: actually it is `storm storm-starter.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology test` where test is Name of Topology