# Running a console type jar file

Tags: java, jar, console-application

I am attempting to run a .jar file that I built. It is a console type application. I have never had any problem running GUI type jars that I built, however the console application will not open.

Comment: That will be because you are doing it wrong.  But if you don't give us more details, we can tell you what your mistake is.

Comment: How do you invoke it?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619196/run-jar-in-console