# The executable jar file exported from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.

I made a simple game to test my skills with Java. The game is working well for now on Eclipse Console, but I'm experiencing a problem while exporting it to as running jar file.

The .jar file I'm exporting with Java > Running jar file is not working at all, and nothing happens when I try to start it on desktop.

I have updated java on my PC.

I kindly request your thoughts with this issue.

Best Regards,

Comment: Hace a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619196/run-jar-in-console. How do you try to run it?

Comment: *How* are you trying to "start it on desktop"? What does that involve?

Comment: I guess, I missed this class:
public class Window extends Canvas {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = NUMBERS;
 public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
  frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
  frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
  frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height)); 
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setResizable(false);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  frame.add(game);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  game.start();
 }
}